# Como pasar un Diagrama de Flujo a Pseudocodigo

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo, diagrama-de-flujo

Hola estoy estudiando desarrollo de software y se me ha dejado una tarea para pasar un diagrama de flujo a pseudocodigo. Avancé todo lo que pude, hasta que PSInt me arrojo un error que dice "en inst. 1: No coinciden los tipos". Les adjunto la captura del diagrama de flujo que se me dejo de tarea y el código con el cual yo he interpretado el diagrama.

[image: Diagrama de Flujo]

[image: Mi Pseudocodigo]

Comment: pseint no es pseudocodigo.. no se de donde sacan eso....

Answer (score 0):

Definiste `p` como entero. Sin embargo `b >= 4 o c != 2` produce un valor lógico. Ese es el problema.

Comment: ¿Me puedes explicar cuál es el objetivo de este diagrama de flujo? ¿Cuál es la consigna?